# How to set Starting program section and Remote control section by powershell for AD user

Tags: active-directory, powershell

I have used the "New-ADUser" command to create a batch of new user. 
However, I need to set the "Program file name" in "Starting program" to "c:\windows\system32\logoff.exe" and "Start in" to "c:\windows\system32\".

[image: Starting program]

Also I need to untick "Require user's permission" in "Remote control"

[image: Remote control]

How can I set these by powershell?
Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Googling for `powershell "start the following program at logon"` yields [this result](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45769659/212107):

Copy&paste from the accepted answer:

```
$ou = [adsi]"WinNT://127.0.0.1"
$user = $ou.psbase.get_children().find("test")
$user.PSBase.InvokeSet("TerminalServicesInitialProgram", "C:\logoff.bat")
$user.setinfo()
```

Googling for `powershell "require users permission"` yields [this result](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/windowsserver/en-US/477887ef-fd30-4450-ad75-3130e2be4e96/active-directory-remote-control-tab-change):

```
$user = [ADSI]"LDAP://CN=UserName,DC=Contoso,DC=Com"
$user.InvokeSet("EnableRemoteControl",2)
$user.SetInfo()
```

Or, from the same thread using the Quest active directory tools:

```
Get-QADUser Kazun | Set-QADUser -TsRemoteControl 2
```

Possible values for RemoteControl:

> **Disable** 0 (0x0)
>   Remote control is disabled.
>
> **EnableInputNotify** 1 (0x1)
>   The user of remote control has full control of the user's session, with the user's permission.
>
> **EnableInputNoNotify** 2 (0x2)
>   The user of remote control has full control of the user's session; the user's permission is not required.
>
> **EnableNoInputNotify** 3 (0x3)
>   The user of remote control can view the session remotely, with the user's permission; the remote user cannot actively control the session.
>
> **EnableNoInputNoNotify** 4 (0x4)
>   The user of remote control can view the session remotely, but not actively control the session; the user's permission is not required.

Comment: I found that "Program file name" use $user.invokeset("TerminalServicesInitialProgram", "C:\logoff.bat") 
and "Start in" use $user.invokeset("TerminalServicesWorkDirectory", "C:\")